# Setting with copy warning with .cumsum

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new column to my pandas dataframe called cumulative cases and have tried using

```
df.loc[:,"cumulative cases"] = df["Cases"].cumsum()
```

this gives me the warning

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```
self.obj[key] = value
```

I don't understand what I have to do to remove this warning, the output is what I wanted even with this warning

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Why not use `df = df.assign(CumulativeCases=lambda df: df.Cases.cumsum())`? IMHO, this looks cleaner and doesn't use any indexing at all

Comment: At some point _before_ this provided code you have unsafely subset your DataFrame. Either `new_df = df[cols]` or `new_df = df[mask]` when it should have been `new_df = df[cols].copy()` or `new_df = df[mask].copy()` The warning is letting you know that `df[mask]['col'] = value` may not work because `df[mask]` may produce a copy and recommends that you use `df.loc[mask, 'col'] = value` but that message is not clear here since you're doing something like `new_df = df[mask]` then later doing `new_df[col] = value` which looks to pandas like a (deferred) `df[mask][col] = value` call.